# Remove Update button from GridView?

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-basic-app

In the view, adding `buttons` creates error page.

How do I remove the `Update` button ?

[image]

Here is my view :

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

        'user.username',
        'title',
        'img_title',
        'note_type',

        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],

        // I do not want the Update button.
        // Adding this 'button' creates a error.
        // 'buttons' => ['{view},{delete}']

    ],
]); ?>
```

The error when adding the 'button'

```
Unknown Property – yii\base\UnknownPropertyException
Setting unknown property: yii\grid\DataColumn::0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, for other users who have the same issue :

The values :

```
['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
```

changed to :

```
[
    'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
    'template' => '{view} {delete}'
],
```

did the trick.